# How do I send Messenger Service alerts in java?

Tags: java, windows-services, native

I'm looking to make a button that says, "Call" that will pop up a message on the appropriate user's computer when there is a problem with the system.

Looking to use this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messenger_service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to use JNI to call a C or C++ DLL.  The DLL can make WinAPI calls to the Messenger Service.

Start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

Comment: Ah. Hopefully it will be possible to do in Java without external DLL's